# No XHR request is fired when calling http function

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, angular2-services

I am struggling to set up a service in angular2 that should communicate with a REST backend.

I was trying to set up a minimal example that should sent requests to a rest backend and process the response. The Service is called correctly and my console shows the message

> 'calling the star wars api';

The problem is that I was checking the xhr tab in the network section of the browser dev tools and **no xhr requests are fired**. 
It seems like the functions extractData and handleError do not seem to be called either although I defined them in map and catch.

Am I missing something here? Why is there no xhr request sent when I call this service?

This is my Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Token } from './token';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getAll() : Observable<Token[]>{
    console.log('calling the star wars api');
    let people$ = this.http
      .get('http://swapi.co/api/people', {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    return people$;
  }
  private getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }


  private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log('data extracted!');
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    console.log('an error ocurred');
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

}
```

I set up the project, component and service with angular-cli. I am using angular2 version 2.4.0

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: What browser? Do you have the console setup to show both info warnings AND errors?

Comment: chromium 53 on ubuntu , I assumed that 'console.log' that I calll manually should show up in any case

Comment: because a piece of the puzzle is missing. If http() is being called, one of those three callbacks will get called, or an error will appear in your console.

Comment: Could that be that there are no consumers for the observable returned from the `getAll()` method?

Comment: I did not define any  Observable <MyClass here> in the  getAll() method is that mandatory?

Comment: Well, your `getAll()` method implicitly returns an `Observable`, because this is what `http.get()` returns. So maybe if you subscribe to this observable (something like `userService.getAll().subscribe(...)`, it will start firing XHR requests? (Sorry I am not well-versed in observables, so might say stupid things)

Comment: @0x2D9A3 thank you your hint with userService.getAll().subscribe() did the trick now the xhr request gets fired. If you want you could make an answer out of your comment and I mark it as correct.

Comment: Nah, you should go ahead and post your solution as an answer (as you have the context and the code), so others with similar issues know what to do. Feel free to use my comments in any way you want if you need. I am just glad it worked for you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to  0x2D9A3's comments I was able to resolve the issue.

The problem was the way that I called the UserService from my component.

```
this.userService.getAll()
```

just called the service but did not fire any XHR request.

Howewer,

```
this.userService.getAll().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        console.log('successfull xhr request');
      }
}
```

Did call the xhr request successfully because this is the way how an Observable has to be consumed.

This is from the angular [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#more-observables)

> Think of an Observable as a stream of events published by some source.
>   To listen for events in this stream, subscribe to the Observable.
>   These subscriptions specify the actions to take when the web request
>   produces a success event (with the data in the event payload) or
>   a fail event (with the error in the payload).